# One-dimensional subspace clustering

Tags: clustering, orthogonal

Consider the inner product space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ and suppose that there are one-dimensional orthogonal subspaces $\{V_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that $\mathbb{R^n} = \oplus_{i=1}^n V_i$.

Now suppose that you observe data $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and each data point belongs to one of the $n$ subspaces. The aim is to group the data into $n$ clusters, one cluster for each subspace. Are there any efficient algorithms to determine such clustering?

The figure below shows an example of a clustering when $n=2$:

[image]

Comment: With your picture, replacing the two dimensions with two principal components does the job of differentiating between the two clouds. In effect, each PC designates its "own" cloud.

Comment: In fact even a Gaussian mixture with flexible covariance matrices should do this properly. (Although you may have a more general problem in mind where point clouds look less Gaussian.)